# Matrix form of a linear functional on $\mathbb F^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

According to my textbook, a linear functional on $\mathbb R^n$, $L:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, in matrix form is given by a transpose. So if $v \in \mathbb R^n$, then the matrix version of $L(v)$ is $[L]^T[v]$ (so, the dual space of $\mathbb R^n$ is $\mathbb R^n$ itself). My question is if I consider $\mathbb C^n$ instead, will the matrix form of linear functional on this space is given by conjugate transpose? If no, namely if only transpose, then is this mere transposition the definition of linear functional on $\mathbb F^n$ for a general field $\mathbb F$?

Comment: What you've said is nonsense, and it's not clear what you actually mean.  By definition, if $[L]$ is the matrix of $L(v)$, then it must satisfy $L(v) = [L][v]$.  We can observe, however, that $[L]$ is $1 \times n$ rather than $n \times 1$, so that it is the transpose of some vector in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: As for your statements on $\Bbb C^n$, it depends on how you define the dual of a complex vector space.  By *your* definition, what is $(\Bbb C^n)^*$?

Comment: $(\mathbb C^n)^*$ is supposed to mean complex transposition. Isn't there only one definition of the dual of vector space, the one whose basis satisfies $e^i(e_j) = \delta_{ij}$ where $\{e^i\}$ and $\{e_j\}$ are bases in the dual and the vector space?

Comment: My book writes, if $v\in V$ and $f \in V^*$, then the matrix representation of $f(v)$ is $[f]^T[v]$. My question is why is it only transposed, without complex conjugation? Is it already how the matrix form of a linear functional defined?